# (Automapper) Multiple Maps with same Conditions redundancy

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

I need to find a better solution to this:

```
public MappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<DesireDto, Desire>()
            .ForMember(x => x.CreationDate, x => x.Ignore())
            .ForMember(x => x.ModifiedDate, x => x.Ignore())
            .ForMember(x => x.ModifiedUser, x => x.Ignore())
            .ForMember(x => x.CreationUser, x => x.Ignore())
            .ForMember(x => x.Language, x => x.Ignore());

        CreateMap<ProductDto, Product>()
            .ForMember(x => x.CreationDate, x => x.Ignore())
            .ForMember(x => x.ModifiedDate, x => x.Ignore())
            .ForMember(x => x.ModifiedUser, x => x.Ignore())
            .ForMember(x => x.CreationUser, x => x.Ignore())
            .ForMember(x => x.Language, x => x.Ignore());
    }
```

I have the same conditions on both but this looks really ugly

This thread lead to nothing: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/2236

Comment: SRP is the best thing. Given that you already have separated DTOs, you have control of small changes. If you glue this things together you will start violating SRP. They are different things, if one change, it shouldn't affect the other. Just keep like this. Sometimes code repetition come for good.

Comment: They are not same conditions, they are different conditions with same names (you named them). Their full names are DesireCreationDate/ProductCreationDate/etc. Unless somewhere in your business handles DesireCreationDate/ProductCreationDate together, it's worthless to abstract an interface like `IWithCreationDate`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ForAllPropertyMaps at the root configuration level. This lets you filter for types, namespaces, property names, and then ignore:

```
cfg.ForAllPropertyMaps(pm => 
    pm.DestinationProperty.DeclaredType.Namespace == "Whatever" && 
    pm.DestinationProperty.Name == "CreationDate", 
    (pm, opt) => opt.Ignore());
```

Then repeat for all your different properties you want to ignore. The namespace makes sure you're only filtering for destination members for types in a certain namespace, but you could do whatever you want based on type metadata.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this :

```
var map1 = CreateMap<DesireDto, Desire>();
var map2 = CreateMap<ProductDto, Product>();

foreach (var s in new []{nameof(DesireDto.CreationDate),nameof(DesireDto.ModifiedDate),nameof(DesireDto.ModifiedUser),nameof(DesireDto.CreationUser),nameof(DesireDto.Language)})
{
   map1.ForMember(s,x=>x.Ignore()) ;
   map2.ForMember(s,x=>x.Ignore()) ;
}
```

but you should listen Fals advice about SRP.

If `DesireDto` and `ProductDto` share some member, maybe you should try to have a base class or an interface, and apply the Ignore rule you want.

Comment: This will make his life even worst, because he'll lose the ability to figure out property changes on compilation time. Also always chose composition over inheritance. As I said Sometimes code repetition come for good.

Comment: @Fals I'm agree with you

Comment: `nameof()` can be used